# Request Randomness not working in localhost network hardhat

Tags: chainlink, hardhat

My contract works just fine when testing on the kovan network.  But on the hardhat localhost network the requestRandomness function fails to execute.

```
function endLottery() public onlyOwner {
    require(LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) * (10**18) >= fee, "Not enough LINK - fill contract with faucet");
    require(state == LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN, "Lottery must be in process");
    // TODO : Make sure that you have participants YOU DONT WANT TO %0
    require(participants.length != 0, "Must have participants to pick a winner");
    state = LOTTERY_STATE.PICKING_WINNER;
    bytes32 requestId = requestRandomness(keyHash, fee);
    emit PickingWinner(requestId);
    emit StateChange("PICKING_WINNER");
}
```

I get the following error

eth_estimateGas

Contract call:       Lottery#endLottery

```
Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string
      at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0x5fbdb2315678afecb367f032d93f642f64180aa3)   
      at Lottery.requestRandomness (@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBase.sol:167)
      at Lottery.endLottery (contracts/Lottery.sol:89)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at EthModule._estimateGasAction (C:\Users\holla\Documents\Blockchain\decentralized-lottery-v2\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\modules\eth.ts:425:7)
      at HardhatNetworkProvider._sendWithLogging (C:\Users\holla\Documents\Blockchain\decentralized-lottery-v2\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\provider.ts:136:22)
      at HardhatNetworkProvider.request (C:\Users\holla\Documents\Blockchain\decentralized-lottery-v2\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\provider\provider.ts:113:18)
      at JsonRpcHandler._handleRequest (C:\Users\holla\Documents\Blockchain\decentralized-lottery-v2\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\jsonrpc\handler.ts:188:20) 
      at JsonRpcHandler._handleSingleRequest (C:\Users\holla\Documents\Blockchain\decentralized-lottery-v2\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\jsonrpc\handler.ts:167:17)
      at Server.JsonRpcHandler.handleHttp (C:\Users\holla\Documents\Blockchain\decentralized-lottery-v2\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\hardhat-network\jsonrpc\handler.ts:52:21)
```

For me this is weird because my test that checks if I can end the lottery is working just fine on the hardhat and localhost networks.  Additionally, the code I have works fine on kovan.  The code I am using to call endLottery() in my frontend is shown below.

```
const endLottery = async () => {
    console.log("--- endLottery called from contractContext ---")
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
    const signer = provider.getSigner()
    const lottery = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, Contract.abi, signer)
    try {
      const endLotteryTx = await lottery.endLottery()
      await endLotteryTx.wait()
      // const pickingWinnerEvent = recipt.events.find(el => el.event === "PickingWinner")
      // const requestId = pickingWinnerEvent.args.requestId
      // console.log("req id", requestId)
      // console.log("recipt", recipt)
      setTotalEther(0)
      setPlayers(0)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('error ending the lottery', e)
    }
  }
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Hi @Holland Pleskac, is the contract funded with enough LINK for the request?

Comment: Wow Harry thank you so much!  I just checked, the LINK balance in the contract was 9 and the fee was 100000000000000000.  I added 18 decimals to the 9 and it worked.  It was because I was funding the contract with

"await mockLinkToken.transfer(lottery.address, 9)"

I just changed that line to fund link to the contract with 

"await hre.run("fund-link", { contract: lottery.address, linkaddress: mockLinkToken.address })"

which I think it better.

Thank you so much lol I was struggling with this for a few days now!

Comment: nice one! Glad to hear you got it working!